# How use custom dkim selector on mailu?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dkim

I have a server with mailu installed and would like to know how to use a specific dkim selector.

I tried putting a file inside mailu/overrides/rspamd/dkim.conf

```
selector = "dkim1";
path = "/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/$domain.$selector.key";
```

and also mailu/overrides/rspamd/dkim_signing.conf

```
dkim_signing {
allow_envfrom_empty = true;
allow_hdrfrom_mismatch = false; 
allow_hdrfrom_multiple = false; 
allow_username_mismatch = false; 
path = "/var/lib/rspamd/dkim/$domain.$selector.key"; 
selector = "dkim1"; 
sign_authenticated = true; 
sign_local = true; 
symbol = "DKIM_SIGNED"; 
try_fallback = true; 
use_domain = "header"; 
use_esld = true; 
use_redis = true; 
key_prefix = "DKIM_KEYS";
}
```

but apparently I was not successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, just set the variable "DKIM_SELECTOR" in "mailu.env"